# Problems with reassignInPackage

Tags: r, debugging, package

I am trying to understand the way the `YourCast` `R` package works and make it work with my data.

For example, if a function produces errors, I

- get the source code of that function using `YourCast:::bad.fn`
- add outputs of critical
  values at critical stages
- use `reassignInPackage(name="original.fn", package="YourCast", value="my.fn")`

Once I find the cause of the error, I fix it in the function and reassign it in the package.

However, for some strange reason this does not work for non-hidden functions.

For example:

```
install.packages("YourCast")
Library(YourCast)
YourCast:::check.depvar
```

This will print the *hidden* function `check.depvar`. One line `if (all(ix == 1:3))` will produce an error message if any of the `x` is missing.

Thus, I change the whole function to the following and replace the original formula:

```
mzuba.check.depvar <- function(formula)
{
 return (grepl("log[(]",as.character(formula)[2]))
}

reassignInPackage("check.depvar", 
                  pkgName="YourCast", 
                  mzuba.check.depvar)
rm(mzuba.check.depvar)
```

Now `YourCast:::check.depvar` will print my version of that function, and everything is fine.

However

`YourCast::yourcast` or `YourCast:::yourcast` or simply `yourcast` will print the *non-hidden* function `yourcast`. Suppose I want to change that function as well.

```
reassignInPackage(name="yourcast", 
              pkgName="YourCast", 
              value=test)
```

Now, `YourCast::yourcast` and `YourCast:::yourcast` will print the new, modified version but `yourcast` *still gives the old version*!

That might not a problem if I could simply call `YourCast::yourcast` instead of `yourcast`, but that produces some kind of error *that I can't trace back because suddenly R-Studio does not print error messages at all anymore!*, although it still *does something* if it is capable to:

```
> Uagh! do something!
> 1 + 1
[1] 2
> Why no error msg?
>
```

Restarting the R-session will solve the error-msg problem, though.

So my question is: **How do I reassign non-hidden functions in packages**?

Furthermore (this would faciliate testing a lot), is there a way to make all hidden functions available without using the `:::` operator? I.e., **How to export all functions from a package**?

Comment: Regarding your last question: Get the source of the package, change the NAMESPACE file, and build the package?

Comment: Thanks. Editing the NAMESPACE file would reqire me to list all functions, but there are hundreds. However I don’t even have to build the package as I can simply use `sourceDirectory()` from `Rutils`.

Comment: Putting `exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")` in NAMESPACE would be sufficient. No need to list all functions.